# "incorrect inclusion of a cudart header" error on CUDA

Tags: cuda, compiler-errors, runtime-error

For mathematical operations, I added to header file

```
#include <math_functions.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
```

but when I compiled it, it started to give the below error. What should I do?

**p.s.:** CUDA 5.0, VS2010

> NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\crt/func_macro.h(50):
>   fatal error C1189: #error :  -- incorrect inclusion of a cudart header
>   file

Comment: Make sure you are including these headers in a `cu` file, not in a `cpp` file.

Comment: You should never need to include any of those headers into user code.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap #include "math_functions.h" with #define and #undef like so:

```
#define __CUDA_INTERNAL_COMPILATION__
#include "math_functions.h"
#undef __CUDA_INTERNAL_COMPILATION__
```

And it seems that math_functions.h may not be included into .cpp file.